# Como eliminar no solo los row de datagrid, si no tambien las columnas desde los header c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Estoy haciendo esto para borrar los rows de mi datagrid.Rows.Clear(); esto me borra las filas, pero me deja los encabezado y yo quiero borrar tambien las columnas, como le hago?

las filas y columnas son agregados por codigo datagrid.rows.add(), no se llena con datasource y base de datos.

Gracias.

Comment: agregaste de manera manual las columnas? en el datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta con esto.
si dices que no lo agregaste mediante un datasource

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```